# Submitting MPI jobs on SGE using Rmpi

Tags: r, mpi, snow

*UPLOADED

I'm trying to submit a job on SGE using MPI. The R script uses Rmpi and snow. 
In the SGE script I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Run with current set of modules and in the current directory
#$ -V -cwd

#Request some time- min 15 mins - max 48 hours 
#$ -l h_rt=1:00:00
# Request 4 CPU cores(processes)
#$ -pe ib 4

#Get email at start and end of the job
#$ -m abe
#$ -M bnldd@leeds.ac.uk

#Now run the job
mpirun -n 4 /apps/applications/R/3.5.0/1/default/bin/R --no-save -q <snowe.R>   snowe.Rout
```

And the following R script snowe.R:

```
library(snow)
library(Rmpi)
p <- rnorm(123, m=33)
cl <- makeCluster(3, type="MPI")
### sends function to each system
clusterCall( cl, function() Sys.info()[c("nodename","machine")])
clusterCall( cl, function() rnorm(1, 33,1 ) )
myNorms <- matrix( rnorm(1000), ncol=10 )
## goes column by column
mypapply <- parApply(cl, myNorms, 2,  print )
attributes(mypapply)
mypapply <- parApply(cl, myNorms, 2, mean )
mypapply
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

The system produces the following error, inside snowe.Rout file:

> library(snow)
>
> library(Rmpi)
>
> ### >

mpirun has exited due to process rank 2 with PID 0 on
node dc1s0b1a exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
   the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
   for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
   then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.
2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
   By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
   exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"
3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter
   orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case, the run-time cannot
   detect that the abort call was an abnormal termination. Hence, the only
   error message you will receive is this one.

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).

You can avoid this message by specifying -quiet on the mpirun command line.

Which could be the problem?

Comment: Try using `./R` ... That is, `mpirun -np 4 ./R --no-save  ...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now something start, but it produces the following error: --------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open MPI tried to fork a new process via the "execve" system call but
failed.  Open MPI checks many things before attempting to launch a
child process, but nothing is perfect. This error may be indicative
of another problem on the target host, or even something as silly as
having specified a directory for your application. Your job will now
abort.

Comment: Is the directory where the executable `R` is located shared across the MPI nodes? In other words, can nodes see `R`?

Comment: I am trying to submit the job on university Supercomputer, actually I don't know where R is located. How could I get this?

Comment: Now I found that the path of R is:/apps/applications/R/3.5.0/1/default/bin/ ; while, the path of mpirun is /apps/mpi/bin/. Do I have to copy the R file into "/apps/mpi/bin/" ? Thank you

Comment: Sorry my original comment was wrong. I thought `R` is an executable that you have compiled. I didn't realize you meant `R` the programming language. Try using the full path, that is, `mpirun -np 4 /apps/applications/R/3.5.0/1/default/bin/R --no-save ...`.

Comment: Thank you! Now, it seems working. the script has been launched, but it remain blocked after the first line. As from the .Rout file:                                                  > library(Rmpi)
> 
> >

Comment: This is the trial script I am trying to submit:                                                   library('Rmpi')
library('parallel')
n.cores <- mpi.universe.size()
cl <- makeCluster(n.cores, type='MPI')
result <- parLapply(cl, 1:n.cores,
           function (i) {system2('hostname', stdout=TRUE)})
summary(factor(unlist(result)))
save.image("/home/home02/bnldd/coresData.RData")
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()

Comment: It produces the following error:                                                                         mpirun has exited due to process rank 2 with PID 0 on
node dc1s0b1a exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could occur:
1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

Comment: 2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"
3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter
orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case, the run-time cannot
detect that the abort call was an abnormal termination. Hence, the only
error message you will receive is this one.

Comment: please update edit your question and add these details and code. The comments are not the best place to share code because of the formatting.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have updated my question. Thanks